# How would you write this script, which works perfectly as intended in bash, to work on fish shell?

Tags: fish

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(date)" git commit --amend --no-edit --date "$(date)"
```

This works fine in bash, but I can't get it to run in fish shell. Can someone help me figure out what is the equivalent in fish shell? Thanks.

Comment: Fish is not a POSIX compatible shell like bash. So it is not surprising your example fails when executed by fish. The fish and bash shells support two incompatible shell syntaxes. Apparently you did not spend even a few minutes reading the fish documentation before opening this discussion thread.

Comment: Hey, next time it would be helpful if you'd post the code you tried to get to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is an equivalent script that doesn't need to use $(date)

```
git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit
```

That does the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In fish, use the `env` external command to alter the environment only for the duration of one command. And of course the command substitution syntax and quoting are different:

```
env GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=(date) git commit --amend --no-edit --date (date)
```